# Can I make a proper website by using ganache and truffle? Like maybe abc.com?

Tags: truffle, dapps, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ganache

I have developed a voting system usinh dapp that runs on local host. It uses accounts from ganache and metamask for transactions of votes. Now if i want to buy a domain and make the thing work, is it possible? Do dapps run on websites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ganache is a local ethereum client that is mostly used for testing. It will skip some verifications at transaction and block level.

I'd suggest for production to use a real client like geth.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can run your Dapps on website as well provided you need to make a connectivity to your local ethereum blockchain running in Ganache. You can have it set up to both dev testing using Ganache and prod release that will actually connect to **main** net or stage release that will connect to **ropsten** (test network).

As suggested by Ismael, you can use a real geth client or you can use the network provided by [Infura](https://infura.io/) .

Comment: Just to be clear, Ropsten is a test network, and shouldn't be used in production. Test networks can disappear at any time, and any test ether associated with them should be considered to be worthless.

Comment: Thanks @RichardHorrocks , referring your comment I have updated the answer.